# Protoc did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information

Tags: spring, spring-boot, grpc

I am trying to run a grpc spring boot example https://github.com/TechPrimers/grpc-spring-boot-example

This is greeting.proto. I don't figure out any syntax errors in this file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package com.techprimers.grpc;

option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.techprimers.grpc";

service GreetingService {
  rpc greeting(GreetingRequest) returns (GreetingResponse) {
  }
}

message GreetingRequest {
  string message = 1;
}

message GreetingResponse {
  string message = 1;
}
```

when I build .proto file, I catch this error.

```
anhtrt@des-1031:~/Documents/grpc-spring-boot-example/greeting-common$ ./mvnw clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Detecting the operating system and CPU architecture
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] os.detected.name: linux
[INFO] os.detected.arch: x86_64
[INFO] os.detected.version: 5.13
[INFO] os.detected.version.major: 5
[INFO] os.detected.version.minor: 13
[INFO] os.detected.release: ubuntu
[INFO] os.detected.release.version: 20.04
[INFO] os.detected.release.like.ubuntu: true
[INFO] os.detected.release.like.debian: true
[INFO] os.detected.classifier: linux-x86_64
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< com.techprimers:greeting-common >-------------------
[INFO] Building greeting-common 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ greeting-common ---
[INFO] Deleting /home/anhtrt/Documents/grpc-spring-boot-example/greeting-common/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile (default) @ greeting-common ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 proto file(s) to /home/anhtrt/Documents/grpc-spring-boot-example/greeting-common/target/generated-sources/protobuf/java
[ERROR] PROTOC FAILED: /home/anhtrt/Documents/grpc-spring-boot-example/greeting-common/target/protoc-plugins/protoc-3.14.0-osx-x86_64.exe: 3: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

[ERROR] /home/anhtrt/Documents/grpc-spring-boot-example/greeting-common/src/main/proto/greeting.proto [0:0]: /home/anhtrt/Documents/grpc-spring-boot-example/greeting-common/target/protoc-plugins/protoc-3.14.0-osx-x86_64.exe: 3: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.428 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-15T09:46:26+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.xolstice.maven.plugins:protobuf-maven-plugin:0.6.1:compile (default) on project greeting-common: protoc did not exit cleanly. Review output for more information. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I also find some same questions but none of them can address this difficult problem.

Comment: Could you show use the content of the following local file: `/home/anhtrt/Documents/grpc-spring-boot-example/greeting-common/src/main/proto/greeting.proto`.

Comment: `Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`  the error description is enough to solve your problem, just edit the `greeting.proto` to meet the syntax restriction

Answer (score 0):

In the plugin configuration, use the below xml.
here hard coded to osx since grpc doesn't have compiler for m1 chips yet.

```
<configuration> 
    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.4.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact> 
</configuration>
```